# RecursionError in Project Euler #5

Tags: python, recursion

I'm receiving a "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error when executing my program to solve this problem. Project Euler's [question #5](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5) asks to find:

> The smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 10.

I've tried to write a program that recursively checks if `x` is divisible by each integer 1-10, and if it doesn't then we call it again with `x` incremented by 1 and repeat until `x`  is found.  (In this case the answer is 2520, which is why I added the if statement.)

```
def euler5(x):

    if x < 2521:
        for i in range(1, 11):
            if x % i == 0:
                print(x)

            else:
                euler5(x+1)

    else:
        print(x)


x = 2
print(euler5(x))
```

Comment: Why are you using recursion, and not a loop?

Comment: If you already know the answer, why do you need the code? :) In all seriousness, though, the code is supposed to work without a limit check, thats the idea of the problem - to find the number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that Python (or CPython, at least) has a limited stack size and no tail call optimization.  So you cannot use unbounded recursion in Python, unlike Scheme (for example).

The solution is to use a regular loop:

```
x = 0
while True:
    x += 1
    # Put loop body here
```

Answer (score -1):

In you defined function, you could you a loop even if you do not know math functions. However, your code is not efficient as program has to keep checking the values to see if it matches the condition. Recursion is not recommended as it should be flexible to be used with other values not just for this question. Euler questions are meant to train your coding practices.

A better method can be used to simplify your code:

```
from functools import reduce
from fractions import gcd
def lcm(a,b):
    return a*b//gcd(a,b) #gcd is greatest common divisor AKA HCF

print (reduce(lcm, range(1, 20+1)))
```

Comment: Don't you think explaining the problem with the code is better than giving an optimal answer?

Comment: I'll argue that Euler problems are meant to test math knowledge, not necessarily code practice. For example, a multiple of 2 is needed, so you don't need to iterate single digits. Also, not even every other digit because a multiple of 5 is needed. Similar tests can be ran for other digits. That greatly increases the speed of the code.